# Maven: How do I activate a profile from command line?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

This is a snippet from my pom.xml.
I tried the following, but the profile was not activated.

```
mvn clean install -Pdev1
mvn clean install -P dev1
```

When I tried `mvn help:active-profiles` no profiles were listed as active.
If I set `<activeByDefault>` for `dev1` to `true`, and run  `mvn help:active-profiles`, it shows me the profile is activated.

```
<profile>
        <id>dev1</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <env>local</env>
                            <properties.file>src/test/resources/dev1.properties</properties.file>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/dev1.testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev2</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <env>local</env>
                            <properties.file>src/test/resources/dev2.properties</properties.file>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/dev2.testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I am wondering why my profile is not getting activated. Has anyone encountered similar issue?

Comment: At least with maven 3.5.3 `-P` does work as expected...FWIW...

Answer (score 137):

Both commands are correct :

```
mvn clean install -Pdev1
mvn clean install -P dev1
```

The problem is most likely not profile activation, but rather the profile **not accomplishing what you expect it to**.

It is normal that the command :

```
mvn help:active-profiles
```

does not display the profile, because is does not contain `-Pdev1`. You could add it to make the profile appear, but it would be pointless because you would be testing maven itself.

What you should do is **check the profile behavior** by doing the following :

1. set `activeByDefault` to `true` in the profile configuration,
2. run `mvn help:active-profiles` (to make sure it is now always activated, even without `-Pdev1`),
3. run `mvn install`.

It should produce the same result as before, and therefore confirm that the problem is the profile not doing what you expect.

Comment: yes, when I set activeByDefault to true, it shows under mvn help:active-profiles. But executing mvn clean install -Pdev1 does not active the profile.

Comment: What's the difference between `activeByDefault` being `true` and `activeProfile`?

Answer (score 17):

Activation by system properties can be done as follows

```
<activation>
    <property>
        <name>foo</name>
        <value>bar</value>
    </property>
</activation>
```

And run the mvn build with -D to set system property

```
mvn clean install -Dfoo=bar
```

This method also helps select profiles in transitive dependency of project artifacts.

Comment: In my case properties are not replacing place holders in *.properties, can you please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186963/value-from-maven-profile-properties-is-not-getting-used-in-properties-file

Answer (score 13):

I have encountered this problem and i solved mentioned problem by adding `-DprofileIdEnabled=true` parameter while running mvn cli command.

Please run your mvn cli command as : `mvn clean install -Pdev1 -DprofileIdEnabled=true`.

In addition to this solution, you don't need to remove **activeByDefault** settings in your POM mentioned as previouses answer.

I hope this answer solve your problem.

Comment: Someone might want to skip tests too for faster builds
    mvn clean install -Prelease -DprofileIdEnabled=true -DskipTests

Answer (score 8):

Just remove activation section, I don't know why -Pdev1 doesn't override default false activation. But if you omit this:

`<activation>
     <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
 </activation>`

then your profile will be activated only after explicit declaration as -Pdev1