# How to pass arguments via command line to maven settings.xml?

Tags: java, maven-3, settings

I need to activate profiles based on environment specifics in Spring Boot Maven application. I configured profiles in **settings.xml**

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault> </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>devRepo</id>
                    <url>https://customRepo/maven/v1</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>

        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>qa</id>
        <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault> </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>qaRepo</id>
                    <url>https://customRepo2/maven/v1</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
```

I tried by activating the profiles using commands `-Pdev`

```
mvn spring-boot:run -s settings.xml -D"spring-boot.run.profiles"=dev help:active-profiles
```

But profiles are not activated properly. **But It's working by adding `activeprofiles` tags.**

```
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>dev</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
```

But I need to activate the profiles environment specific like

```
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>$env</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
```

Any way we can pass arguments to `activeProfile` in settings.xml file? Similar like this `-Denv`

Reference:

[Maven: How do I activate a profile from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927064/maven-how-do-i-activate-a-profile-from-command-line)

[Configure active profile in SpringBoot via Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390860/configure-active-profile-in-springboot-via-maven)

https://mkyong.com/maven/maven-profiles-example/

http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to this line of description:
"Activation occurs when all specified criteria have been met, though not all are required at once." from http://maven.apache.org/settings.html  in Profiles section
and consider to define application.properties in your project and add line with this config:
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
I hope this work.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried by adding the properties but still no luck.