# How to run one profile in Maven from two profiles?

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, maven-profiles

I'm creating a testing framework with Java 11 and Maven, and I have build two different runners for separate tests. I want to run only one profile but it keeps running both of them. Here are my profiles:

```xml
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>smoke</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.21.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>smoke</id>
                                <configuration>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/SmokeRunnerTest.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>functional</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.21.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>functional</id>
                                <configuration>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/FunctionalRunnerTest.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: What are you using to run maven?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven: How do I activate a profile from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927064/maven-how-do-i-activate-a-profile-from-command-line)

Comment: terminal command mvn clean install -P functional, but it runs both of them after one another

Comment: Maybe the failsafe plugin ends up including both classes? Try excluding **.

Comment: Why are those things named like a unit test? `*Test.java` instead of an `*IT.java`based on the usage of the failsafe plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can put

```
<activation>
  <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```

into profiles' definition to avoid unneeded profile activation.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Still running two profiles, I used mvn clean install -P functional

Comment: I think your problem is not with profiles it's that you need to exclude all classes from failsafe plugin before including the required one.

Comment: @alamar, Are you able to answer this question by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104529/can-maven-run-both-cucumber-junit-and-testng-runners-together